# Hosting Multiple Mautic Instances with 50,000 Contacts Each

Tags: performance, server, mautic

I have a question regarding the performance and capacity of a server based on an Intel Core i9 9900k processor with 64GB of RAM for hosting multiple instances of Mautic. I would like to know if this configuration is powerful enough to handle the load of approximately 50,000 contacts per Mautic instance.

I understand that the actual performance will depend on various factors such as the intended usage, other services running on the server, and the overall workload. However, I would appreciate a general estimation of the capacity of this server.

1. How many instances of Mautic, with 50,000 contacts each, can reasonably be hosted on a server equipped with an Intel Core i9 9900k processor and 64GB of RAM without compromising performance?
2. Are there any potential bottlenecks or specific factors that I should consider to optimize Mautic's performance on this type of configuration?

Any insights, experiences, or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I have very little experience in hosting. However, managed  cloud servers often only give you up to 4 Gb Memory and two cores of whatever mediocre processor - for single instance purposes. That might give you a first indicator (although it’s a poor one).
Does the system have to work without delay?
Will the Mautic instances work parallel 24/7? Will they bombard the subscribers/clients/customers with emails? What are the planned operations?
I find it very hard to guess. So this is my (obvious) advice:

Start with a low number of instances and run a test. From there on you go higher to the point where the system is at somewhat 90%. That’s your max of instances that I would go for.